# Not able to download and parallelly open a file object stored in server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried to download and opened a file object stored in Server, but not able to open the file post download. Please find the sample code I am trying as below. I have used Content-Disposition to inline, but still it is not working as mentioned in other solution to this problem. It just downloads, but don't open. Any help please on this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = this.Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/48A4-4972-AEBE-8E7C11AE64AF");
    
    string fileName = "crma.jpg";
    FileStream stream = null;
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    long dataToRead;
    try
    {
        stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        dataToRead = stream.Length;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + "\"" + fileName + "\"");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataToRead.ToString());
        response.ContentType = "application/jpg";
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
        while (dataToRead > 0)
        {
            if (response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                response.Flush();
                buffer = new Byte[10000];
                dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
            }
            else
            {
                dataToRead = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
        response.End();
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: A website cannot download and automatically run the downloaded file. Users need to manually click on the downloaded file from the browser interface or the file browser to actually open it.

Comment: Imagine if a website could do this: you visit a compromised website and suddenly `ransomware-virus.exe` is downloaded to your computer and automatically run by the website. Now all of your files are encrypted unless you pay them money, all because you simply visited the page. Thankfully the web doesn't work like this, and users have to choose to open files after they've been downloaded. It doesn't protect everyone 100% but it prevents a site automatically dropping a virus onto your machine and executing it.